# Sum of two normal variables conditional

Tags: probability

Assume $h$ and $s$ are two independent normal random variables, with means $\mu_h, \mu_s$ and  variances $\sigma_h^2 , \sigma_s^2$.

For any $a,b\in R$ I want to compute:

$Pr(h+s>a | h<a-b)$

I am using bayes rule, but Im not sure how to get the expression of $P(h+s>a \land h<a-b)$, can I simplify the two events to compute the probability easier?

Thanks

Comment: $Pr(h+s > a, h < a - b) = Pr(a-s< h < a - b) = \int Pr(a-s< h < a - b|s=s)f_s(s)ds = \int (F_h(a-b) - F_h(a-s)) f_s(s)ds$ 

where $F_h(x)$ is a CDF of $h$, and $f_s(x)$ is a pdf of $s$. Maybe it'll help

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method is using the law of total probability ($f_H(h)$ is the PDF of $H$):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(H + S > a| H < a - b) &= \int_{}\mathbb{P}(H + S > a| H < a - b, H = h) d\, \mathbb{P}(H \leq h| H< a - b)\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{a - b} \mathbb{P}(H + S > a| H = h) \cdot \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(H < a - b)}\cdot f_H(h) \,dh\\
&= \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(H < a - b)} \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{a - b} \mathbb{P}(S > a - h) \cdot  f_H(h) \,dh
\end{aligned}
$$